# Currency Type (Object) Updating Causing Error as "RSF CALCULATION IS IN PROGRESS"

Tags: c#, currencytype

I am using the below code to integrate with salesforce. I will receive the exchange rate from the JSON webservice and update the currency type object. the code works fine. It's not all the rates are updating at the same time. Sometimes its update. Some time i am getting error as "**RSF CALCULATION IN PROGRESS**" "**ALREADY_UPDATE_IN_PROCESS**" in the **updatedResults**  of below my code.

```
 private void UpdateExchangeRate(SforceService sfdcBinding)
        {
        QueryResult qr = sfdcBinding.queryAll("SELECT Id, IsoCode, ConversionRate  FROM CurrencyType where isactive =true and IsoCode != 'SGD'");

        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(GET("http://rates.XXX.com/index.php?sf"));
        SaveResult[] updatedResults;
        if (qr.done)
        {
            if (qr.size > 0)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < qr.records.Length; t++)
                {
                    CurrencyType Cur = (CurrencyType)qr.records[t];

                    if (Cur.IsoCode == "USD") 
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["USD"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "EUR")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["EUR"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "CHF")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["CHF"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "JPY")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["JPY"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "CNY")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["CNY"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "DKK")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["DKK"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "THB")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["THB"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "GBP")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["GBP"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "MYR")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["MYR"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }
                    else if (Cur.IsoCode == "IDR")
                    {
                        CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType();
                        Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
                        Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"]["IDR"]["rate"])).Value);
                        Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true;
                        updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(new sObject[] { Currency });
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incredibly over-complicated. The following version should work just as well:

```
private void UpdateExchangeRate(SforceService sfdcBinding) {
  QueryResult qr = sfdcBinding.query("SELECT Id, IsoCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType where isactive =true and IsoCode IN ('USD','EUR','CHF','JPY','CNY','DKK','THB','GBP','MYR','IDR')"); 
  JObject rss = JObject.Parse(GET("http://rates.XXX.com/index.php?sf")); 
  sObject[] updates = new sObject[qr.records.Length];
  for(int i = 0; i < updates.Length; i++)  {
    CurrencyType Cur = (CurrencyType)qr.records[i];
    CurrencyType Currency = new CurrencyType(); 
    Currency.Id = qr.records[t].Id;
    Currency.ConversionRate = Convert.ToDouble(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(rss["sgd"][Cur.IsoCode]["rate"])).Value);
    Currency.ConversionRateSpecified = true; 
    updates[i] = Currency;
  }
  updatedResults = sfdcBinding.update(updates);
}
```

---

### Notes

**Do not** use Not Equals as a filter when you can help it, as it causes full table scans (bad for performance).

**Do not** use queryAll unless you need to query deleted records (bad for performance).

**Do not** write code over and over again with only minor modifications. We call this **d**on't **r**epeat **y**ourself (DRY principle).

**Do** perform your updates in a batch instead of singly (good for performance).

**Do** learn more about the `done` flag. You shouldn't use it to control if you enter the loop at all; if there were more than 2,000 records, none of them would have been updated.

Instead, done lets you know if you need to query more records. I'm on my phone right now, but please look up the queryMore example in the online documentation.

Comment: thank u so much for your post.. Simply amazing learnt a bit how to write the code in efficient way in sales force.